# Why is my system taking almost two minutes to start?

Tags: boot, 17.10, startup

It's recently been reloaded, bit it's taking a ridiculous amount of time to start up.

I've attached the tail end of the dmesg log, although I not really sure what any of it means so I'm after some tips as to where to look and what I potentially need to do.

So does this mean it took 16 seconds for that snd_hda_codec_hdmi thing to complete, or that it took 16 seconds for the rfkill: input handler disabled to complete?

### dmesg tail

```
[   31.423513] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp2s0: link becomes ready
[   32.207818] audit: type=1400 audit(1519758834.340:47): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap.slack.slack" pid=1592 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   33.370335] audit: type=1400 audit(1519758835.503:48): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/snap/core/4110/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=1615 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   33.384467] audit: type=1400 audit(1519758835.517:49): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/snap/core/4110/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper" pid=1615 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   33.384726] audit: type=1400 audit(1519758835.517:50): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/snap/core/4110/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//snap_update_ns" pid=1615 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   33.566711] audit: type=1400 audit(1519758835.699:51): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap.core.hook.configure" pid=1670 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   34.756264] audit: type=1400 audit(1519758836.889:52): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap.datagrip.datagrip" pid=1738 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   35.523826] audit: type=1400 audit(1519758837.656:53): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap.discord.discord" pid=1777 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   39.206997] audit: type=1400 audit(1519758841.339:54): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="docker-default" pid=1924 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   45.475862] nvidia-modeset: Allocated GPU:0 (GPU-734a2991-20e6-aaeb-57d1-343f4d445979) @ PCI:0000:01:00.0
[   52.324100] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC2D0: HDMI: invalid ELD data byte 13
[   69.792131] bridge: filtering via arp/ip/ip6tables is no longer available by default. Update your scripts to load br_netfilter if you need this.
[   69.794302] Bridge firewalling registered
[   69.892720] nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (65536 buckets, 262144 max)
[   70.690942] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
[   70.725823] Netfilter messages via NETLINK v0.30.
[   70.733375] ctnetlink v0.93: registering with nfnetlink.
[   71.358229] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): br-46abd666c673: link is not ready
[   71.401112] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): br-6dda0bd6942c: link is not ready
[   71.449784] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): br-a09ff5d997e8: link is not ready
[   71.635022] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): br-a4e04f927837: link is not ready
[   71.682636] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): docker0: link is not ready
[   86.887899] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC2D0: HDMI: invalid ELD data byte 70
[   90.595490] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC2D0: HDMI: invalid ELD data byte 14
[  106.470249] rfkill: input handler disabled
```

### systemd-analyze blame

```
     24.081s docker.service
     22.958s plymouth-quit-wait.service
      9.133s snapd.service
      4.965s dev-mapper-ubuntu\x2d\x2dvg\x2droot.device
      4.570s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      4.371s systemd-udev-settle.service
      4.365s NetworkManager.service
      4.030s udisks2.service
      3.784s ModemManager.service
      3.572s accounts-daemon.service
      3.003s networking.service
      2.630s dev-loop8.device
      2.554s dev-loop9.device
      2.498s polkit.service
      2.460s gpu-manager.service
      2.205s dev-loop12.device
      2.154s dev-loop10.device
      2.051s dev-loop11.device
      2.039s grub-common.service
      2.030s dev-loop13.device
      1.970s snap-datagrip-7.mount
      1.917s apparmor.service
      1.726s fwupd.service
      1.574s thermald.service
      1.439s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
      1.340s plymouth-read-write.service
      1.330s rsyslog.service
      1.321s apport.service
      1.218s snap-datagrip-6.mount
      1.201s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-27.mount
      1.033s dev-loop6.device
      1.021s snap-core-4110.mount
       967ms snap-phpstorm-15.mount
       926ms snap-core-4017.mount
       900ms snap-peek-711.mount
       880ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-D853\x2d2306.service
       815ms packagekit.service
       795ms systemd-logind.service
       795ms lm-sensors.service
       794ms avahi-daemon.service
       790ms speech-dispatcher.service
       784ms dev-loop2.device
       773ms snap-google\x2dplay\x2dmusic\x2ddesktop\x2dplayer-47.mount
       771ms snap-slack-4.mount
       705ms keyboard-setup.service
       661ms dev-loop5.device
       643ms snap-datagrip-5.mount
       625ms dns-clean.service
       563ms systemd-modules-load.service
       498ms dev-mqueue.mount
       497ms dev-hugepages.mount
       495ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
       459ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
       458ms snap-discord-52.mount
       451ms dev-loop0.device
       448ms boot-efi.mount
       443ms ufw.service
       433ms dev-loop7.device
       423ms lvm2-activation-early.service
       416ms pppd-dns.service
       414ms alsa-restore.service
       389ms systemd-journald.service
       365ms systemd-udevd.service
       321ms snap-phpstorm-13.mount
       311ms snap-core-3887.mount
       300ms systemd-timesyncd.service
       287ms upower.service
       274ms console-setup.service
       251ms gdm.service
       243ms systemd-resolved.service
       224ms systemd-localed.service
       218ms wpa_supplicant.service
       206ms kmod-static-nodes.service
       191ms kerneloops.service
       184ms systemd-hostnamed.service
       170ms plymouth-start.service
       167ms systemd-timedated.service
       165ms systemd-sysctl.service
       161ms colord.service
       159ms dev-loop4.device
       138ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service
       137ms NetworkManager-dispatcher.service
       132ms dev-loop3.device
       132ms systemd-update-utmp.service
       128ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       125ms snap-phpstorm-14.mount
       124ms systemd-user-sessions.service
       103ms lvm2-monitor.service
        83ms lvm2-activation.service
        74ms dev-mapper-ubuntu\x2d\x2dvg\x2dswap_1.swap
        57ms user@1000.service
        57ms systemd-remount-fs.service
        51ms user@121.service
        49ms systemd-journal-flush.service
        44ms rtkit-daemon.service
        28ms setvtrgb.service
        26ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video1.service
        24ms systemd-random-seed.service
        15ms snapd.socket
        15ms docker.socket
        12ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         4ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
         3ms sys-kernel-config.mount
         3ms nvidia-persistenced.service
         2ms dev-loop1.device
```

### /etc/fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=D853-2306  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: Could you please add `systemd-analyze blame` output to the question?

Comment: When you say 'reloaded' to you mean a re-install ?  If so, I would not be surprised if one of your disk partitions if not properly defined in /etc/fstab.

Comment: Unless you are actually using IPV6, you should set it to "ignore" in your network connection.

Comment: @N0rbert Requested outputs added. Appreciate the help! Looks like a bunch of time is docker starting up (I'm assuming these are singular times sorted desc, rather than incremental?), I wonder if I can delay that until a few seconds after I've logged in.. Then the next major is plymouth-quit-wait.service... Not sure what to do about that one